# How to add dictionary to json object

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, textblob

In my construct below, I am trying to pass a JSON object through my web service. As a new requirement I have to pass a dictionary object which is `sent` in the code below. Can you please guide me how to add the dictionary to JSON object?

```
if plain_text is not None:
        blob = TextBlob(plain_text)
        sentiment = TextBlob(plain_text)
        sent = {}
        for sentence in blob.sentences:
            sent[sentence] =sentence.sentiment.polarity
        print sent
        return json.dumps(
            {'input' : plain_text, 
             'Polarity': sentiment.polarity,                 
             #'sent': json.dumps(sent) # this is where I am stuck as this 'sent' is a dict
             },
            indent=4)
```

If I uncomment the line I get the below error:

```
Exception:

TypeError('keys must be a string',)
Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle-0.12.7-py2.7.egg\bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle-0.12.7-py2.7.egg\bottle.py", line 1729, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\RealPy\WebServices\bottle\server_bckup.py", line 53, in sentimentEngine
    'sent': json.dumps(sent),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

Comment: why not {.., 'sent':sent} ?

Comment: If you simply uncomment the line, what happens?

Comment: What does `print sent` print?

Comment: Hello John, print sent print the key value pairs properly. the issue comes when i try to include it in json object.
@Burhan: I have added the error msg as well jus now.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, dictionary keys must be strings. You have a Python dictionary `sent`, that you want to serialize into JSON. This fails, as your dictionary `sent` has keys that are not strings, but `textblob.blob.Sentence` instances.

If it makes sense, you can change your code to read:

```
    for sentence in blob.sentences:
        sent[str(sentence)] = sentence.sentiment.polarity
```

Or, you can customize the Python JSON encoder to know how to serialize TextBlob Sentences.